# How to make a javascript/php chatroom more efficient in terms of load time and sql communication

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, chatroom, mmo

Right now the setup for my javascript chat works so it's like

```
function getNewMessage()
{
     //code would go here to get new messages
     getNewMessages();
}
getNewMessages();
```

And within the function I would use JQuery to make a get post to retrieve the messages from a php scrip which would
1. Start SQL connection
2. Validate that it's a legit user through SQL
3. retrieve only new message since the last user visit
4. close SQL

This works great and the chat works perfectly. My concern is that this is opening and closing a LOT of SQL connections. It's quite fast, but I'd like to make a small javascript multiplayer game now, and transferring user coordinates as well as the tens of other variables 3 times a second in which I'm opening and closing the sql connection each time and pulling information from numerous tables each time might not be efficient enough to run smoothly, and might be too much strain on the server too.

Is there any better more efficient way of communicating all these variables that I should know about which isn't so hard on my server/database?

Comment: Have you tried persistent connections?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't** use persistent connections unless it's the only solution available to you!

When MySQL detects the connection has been dropped, any temporary tables are dropped, any active transaction is rolled back, and any locked tables are unlocked.  Persistent connections only drop when the Apache child exits, not when your script ends, even if the script crashes!  You could inherit a connection in the middle of a transaction.  Worse, other requests could block, waiting for those tables to unlock, which may take quite a long time.

Unless you have *measured how long it takes to connect* and identified it as a very large percentage of your script's run time, you should not consider using persistent connections.  In fact, that should be what you do here, if you're worried about performance.  Check out [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) or [xdebug](http://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug), profile your code, then start optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use a different approach to get the new messages from the server: [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).

Using this technique you do not have to open that much new connections.

Comment: I quite like this, but each connection is using its own process. If I have a lot of users in the chatroom this is going to cause problems, right?

Comment: I presume my webhost (justhost) uses mod_apache. Not much wiggle room here!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

and

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

Answer (score 0):

A couple of dozen players at the same time won't hurt the database or cause noticeable lag if you have efficient SQL statements.  Likely your database will be hosted on the same server or at least the same network as your game or site, so no worries.  If your DB happens to be hosted on a separate server running an 8-bit 16mz board loaded with MSDOS, located in the remote Amazon, connected by radio waves hooked up to a crank-powered generator operatated by a drunk monkey, you're on your own with this one.

Otherwise, really you should be more worried about exactly how much data you're passing back and forth to your players.  If you're passing back and forth coordinates for all objects in an entire world, page load could take a painfully long time, even though the DB query takes a fraction of a second.  This is sometimes overcome in games by a "fog of war" feature which doesn't bother notifying the user of every single object in the entire map, only those which are in immediate range of the player.  This can easily be done with a single SQL query where object coordinates are in proximity to a player.  Though, if you have a stingy host, they will care about the number of connects and queries.

If you're concerned about attracting even more players than that, consider exploring cache methods like pre-building short files storing commonly fetched records or values using `fopen()`, `fgets()`, `fclose()`, etc.  Or, use php extensions like `apc` to store values in memory which persist from page load to page load.  `memcache` or `memcached` also act similarly, but in a way which acts like a separate server you can connect to, store values which can be shared with other page hits, and query.

To update cached pages or values when you think they might become stale, you can run a cron job every so often to update these files or values.  If your host doesn't allow cron jobs, consider making your guests do that legwork: a line of script on a certain page will refresh the cache with new values from a database query after a certain number of page hits.  Or cache a date value to check against on every page hit, and if so much time has passed, refresh the cache.

Again, unless you're under the oppressive thumb of a stingy host, or unless you're getting a hundred or more page hits at a time, no need to even be concerned about your database.  Databases are not that fragile.  If they crashed in a hysterical fit of tears anytime more than one query came their way, the engineers who made it wouldn't have a job for very long.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an annoying "answer" but perhaps you should be thinking about this a different way, after all this is really not the strongest use of a relational database. Have you considered an XMPP solution? IMO this would be the best tool for the job and both ejabberd and openfire are trivial to set up these days. The excellent Strophe library can make the front end story easy, and as an added bonus you get HTTP binding (like commet) so you won't need to poll the server, your latency will go down and you'll be generating less HTTP traffic.

I know it's highly unlikely you're going to change your whole approach just cos I said so, but wanted to provide an alternative perspective.

http://www.ejabberd.im/
http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/